# Search User by Last Name PHP

Tags: php, search

Yahallo! I have a problem in searching the user in the database and displaying them into the textfields. I have set everything to query and search the user by typing the lastname but it gives me an error

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'mysqli_sql_exception' with message 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1' .

```html
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$password ="";
$database = "ntmadb";

$id = "";
$firstname = "";
$lastname = "";
$username = "";

mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

// connect to mysql database
try{
    $connect = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database);
} catch (mysqli_sql_exception $ex) {
    echo 'Error';
}

// get values from the form
function getPosts()
{
    $posts = array();
    $posts[0] = $_POST['id'];
    $posts[1] = $_POST['firstname'];
    $posts[2] = $_POST['lastname'];
    $posts[3] = $_POST['username'];
    return $posts;
}

// Search

if(isset($_POST['search']))
{
    $data = getPosts();
    
    $search_Query = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE lastname = $data[2]";
    
    $search_Result = mysqli_query($connect, $search_Query);
    
    if($search_Result)
    {
        if(mysqli_num_rows($search_Result))
        {
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($search_Result))
            {
                $id = $row['id'];
                $firstname = $row['firstname'];
                $lastname = $row['lastname'];
                $username = $row['username'];
            }
        }else{
            echo 'No Data For This Id';
        }
    }else{
        echo 'Result Error';
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE Html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>PHP INSERT UPDATE DELETE SEARCH</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="index44.php" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="id" placeholder="Id" value="<?php echo $lastname;?>"><br><br>
            <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name" value="<?php echo $firstname;?>"><br><br>
            <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name" value="<?php echo $lastname;?>"><br><br>
            <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="User Name" value="<?php echo $username;?>"><br><br>
            <div>
             
                <!-- Input For Edit Values -->
                <input type="submit" name="update" value="Update">
                
              
                
                <!-- Input For Find Values With The given ID -->
                <input type="submit" name="search" value="Find">
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Can someone assist in fixing it? Thank you!

Comment: (1) string literals need quotes - `'$data[2]'`, (2) array values inside double quotes should be wrapped in curly brackets - `'{$data[2]}'`, (3) you are wide open to sql injection - [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: I didn't knew that, thank you @Sean! But this is just a sample project. This will never go live. But I'll keep that in mind. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below query.

```
$search_Query = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE lastname = '".$data[2]."'";
```

Comment: lastname is a string variable. you have to put it in single quotes in the query

Comment: The other values associated with the last name didn't display on the textfields. :/

Comment: My bad, it was an error in the textfield. It now works! Thank you @Mith.

Comment: Ok, Thanks :) @AzurenRen

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$temp_lastname = $data[2];
$search_Query = "SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE `lastname` = '$temp_lastname'";
```

Comment: I will! Thank you